# Could not resolve placeholder 'AppPropertyDir' in value "file:${AppPropertyDir}/context.properties"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I can't find this question elsewhere when it's dealing with simple string injection!

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration("appPropertiesLoader")
@PropertySource(value = "file:${AppPropertyDir}/context.properties")
public class AppPropertiesLoader {

    @Value("#{systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}")
    private String appPropertyDir;

}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'AppPropertyDir' in value "file:${AppPropertyDir}/context.properties"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
```

Comment: do have this in OS environment variable?

Comment: Have what exactly?

Comment: this `AppPropertyDir`?

Comment: This and then restarting eclipse fixed the issue! thanks